# macro containing COUNTIFS when moved to another computer, returns 0

Tags: excel, vba

Below is an example code for which i get zero when copied to another computer both having same version of excel.

```
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range(.Cells(2, resolve_date), .Cells(lastrow, resolve_date)), ">=" & date1, _
      .Range(.Cells(2, resolve_date), .Cells(lastrow, resolve_date)), "<=" & date2, .Range(.Cells(2, Planned_release), .Cells(lastrow, Planned_release)), rel)
```

same when ran on the computer which i coded, it returns non-zero value(expected), What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Has the another computer the same system date as the first one?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the line of code on both machines - and then examine the content of each parameter in your statement. You'll hopefully find a difference in a parameter that will help you solve your issue...